# Create array from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I have 4 charts each with their own divs in html. I'm trying to find the best way to add these charts to an array automatrically without having to update the array whenever I make a change to the charts and their ID's.

HTML:

```
<table id="dashboard" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="c1"><div class='chartLoadingOverlay'>Loading chart please be patient...</div></td>
        <td id="c2"><div class='chartLoadingOverlay'>Loading chart please be patient...</div></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="c3"><div class='chartLoadingOverlay'>Loading chart please be patient...</div></td>
        <td id="c4"><div class='chartLoadingOverlay'>Loading chart please be patient...</div></td>
        <!--<td id="BottomRight"><div class='chartLoadingOverlay'>Loading chart please be patient...</div></td>-->
    </tr>   
</table>
```

JS:

```
var arrOfChartContainers = ["c1","c2","c3","c4"];  <-- I want to automate this
```

Comment: An array is just a dumb data structure; it can’t update itself. I think what you really want is a method `getChartContainers()` that returns an array of the current chart containers. Would that be okay?

Comment: What ever works really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cFAFU/1)

```
var x = $('.chartLoadingOverlay').closest('td').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(x);
```

[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Comment: You should use `.get()` method, `.map()` returns a jQuery-wrapped array.

Answer (score 1):

@Tushar Gupta has a great answer. Here's my 2 pennies worth though just in case.

```
var arrOfChartContainers = [];
$('table td').each(function() {
    arrOfChartContainers.push(this.id);
});
console.log(arrOfChartContainers);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/CSrbj/1/)